# Colorize Windows scrollbars in apps

Tags: windows-7, windows

User wants to colorize scrollbars (near multiline edit fields) in most apps (e.g. Notepad++) with custom color. E.g. with brown, not light gray. How to do it in Win7?

- For Classic theme I can do it.
- For Windows 7 default theme I cannot do it in Win settings. How to?

Comment: I'm not a wiz at Windows 7 but have you tried to change the current theme (on display settings)?

Comment: I can change for Classic theme only. Can NOT for Win7 theme... (No such setting I can find)